# Twig: conditionally return from a macro

Tags: macros, return, twig

I'd like to conditionally return from a macro, like this pseudocode:

```
{% macro example() %}
    ...
    {% if condition %} {% return %} {% endif %}
    ...
{% endmacro %}
```

Is this possible with Twig, perhaps with a Twig extension?

Comment: [It's not good to use macros return value](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/1497#issuecomment-54506873)

Answer (score 3):

There's no return in twig, but you can wrap the rest of your macro in an `if not condition` block like this:

```
{% macro example() %}
    ...
    {% if not condition %}
    ...
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Keep in mind that twig is a templating language.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to create a return by writing a Twig extension?

Comment: I don't know twigs internals enough to answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% macro example(isTrue) %}
    {% if isTrue %}
        10
    {% else %}
        20
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{% import _self as self %}

{% set aaa = 3 + self.example(true) ~ '' %}
{{ aaa }}

{% set bbb = 3 + self.example(false) ~ '' %}
{{ bbb }}
```

Output:

```
13

23
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example:

```
{# macro #}

{% macro check(isTrue) %}
    {% if isTrue %}
        show-paywall
    {% else %}
        show-content
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}


{# usage #}
{% import _self as self %}

{% set per = self.check(true)|trim %}

{%  if per == 'show-paywall' %}

{{'Show paywall man.'}}

{% else %}

{{ 'You are good man.' }}

{% endif %}
```

You can play online :
https://twigfiddle.com/etn6ef